# `list-directed io syntax error` reading CSV starting in first line in Fortran

Tags: file-io, fortran, intel-fortran

I need to read matrix data from a CSV file. This data is all numeric, but it may not have a fixed format. Here is an example for a file called `Data.csv`

```
1,2.1,3,4
2,3,4.2,5
3,4,5,6.33
4,5,6,7
5,6,7,8
6,7,8,9
7,8,9,10
8,9,10,11
```

I tried two things. First writing a subroutine that reads unformatted data from the CSV file.

```
program main

implicit none
integer,parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
integer,parameter :: N = 8
integer,parameter :: M = 4    
integer           :: i
real(dp)          :: yr(N,M)   

! Reading file using subroutine
call txtr_data_mat('Data.csv',yr)

contains    

subroutine txtr_data_mat(filename,rdata)
    character (len=*),intent(in) :: filename
    real(dp),intent(inout)       :: rdata(:,:)
    integer                      :: n1,n2,i1,i2
    character (60)               :: fnametxt
    fnametxt = trim(filename)
    n1 = size(rdata,1)
    n2 = size(rdata,2)
    open (12, file = fnametxt)
    read (12,*) ((rdata(i1,i2), i2=1,n2), i1=1,n1)
    close(12)
end subroutine txtr_data_mat
    
end program main
```

This gives me an error: `forrtl: severe (59): list-directed I/O syntax error, unit 12, file C:\source\Data.csv`. I also tried something more simple. Rather than using the subroutine above, I tried:

```
open (17, file='Data.csv')
do i = 1,N
    read (17, *) yr(i,:)
end do
close(17)
```

This also produces the same error: `forrtl: severe (59): list-directed I/O syntax error, unit 17, file C:\source\Data.csv`. Strangely, when I read a "blank" line, by adding `read (17, '()')` between the `open` command and the beginning of the loop, it seems to work for a while, but, of couse, it skips the first line, so it reaches the end of the file without having finished (error: `forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit 17, file C:\source\Data.csv`).

Any ideas about how to solve this? I am trying to use a subroutine as the one at the beginning because I need to repeat this same process lot of times for different matrices with different shapes.

Comment: Works fine for me (gfortran 7.4 on Linux). Looks fine to me. Complete guess - do you have an end of line character at the end of the last line? If not try adding one.

Comment: BTW the trim in the subroutine doesn't achieve much, fnametxt is 60 characters long whatever you do, padded with spaces if required. If you want to use trim the easiest place, if you are worried about training blanks, is in the open statement itself - that way you just get the filename and nothing else

Comment: Works for me with ifort 19.1.2 and 2021.1 on Windows x64.  What version are you using/what platform/what compile options?  No point putting trim in even directly on the FILE specifier in OPEN - the rules of the language require that "any trailing blanks are ignored" (F2018 12.5.6.10p1).

Comment: @IanH I am using ifort on Win64 (Version 19.0.5.281 Build 20190815), and I'm not including any compiler option for the code above, so just using ifort main.f90, and then executing main.exe

Comment: @IanBush I checked the CSV file for additional characters. There is one blank line at the end, but removing it doesn't do anything. Adding an space at the end of the last line with data does nothing as well. The CSV files are produced by another person in another program, so, in general, I have limited control over that.

Comment: Well I'm afraid I can only presume there's something different in the file you are reading compared to the one I obtained by cutting and pasting the above into a file. Another complete guess - have you checked that there are no extraneous control characters in the file? [Don't know how you go about doing that under Windows]

Comment: Hmmm - what happens if YOU cut and paste the above into a new file and try and read that?

Comment: @IanBush Ok, so it seems that it has to do with the encoding. The original CSV has UTF-8 with BOM encoding. When I paste the same data in a new text file with UTF-8 encoding everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is UTF-8 encoded, you should inform the compiler in the OPEN statement, using an ENCODING specifier.

That given, there is arguably a compiler runtime bug in current Intel Fortran versions, when it is told the encoding and still fails to handle the BOM marker, given the Unicode specification of the UTF-8 encoding scheme.