# `list-directed I/O syntax error` when reading an integer value from a file to a real variable

Tags: file-io, fortran

For example:

```
real :: a(3)
open(newunit=u,file='t.txt', status='old')
do j=1,3
  read(u,*) a(j)
enddo
```

Data in 't.txt' looks like:

```
1 
2 
3
```

Code compiled by `ifort` gives the following error:

```
forrtl: severe (59): list-directed I/O syntax error
```

I tried serveral compiling options, still getting the error.

Why ifort can not handle this simple data conversion?

--update---
It is due to a semi-colon accidentally appearing in the data file, it is not related to integer->real conversion. Gfortran can read that file without problems, but ifort gives the above error.

Comment: Check the exact content of the file including all unprintable characters. For this short file you can show the full hexdump. However, the "syntax-error" bit is peculiar, show also a complete [mcve] for the Fortran code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code (assuming u is declared as an integer, but then it wouldn't get past the open statement if it wasn't). Please show a whole code that reproduces the problem - are you sure that it is that snippet which is triggering the error?

Comment: I can only reproduce that error message by putting additional spurious characters in the input file. (Although my version of ifort also gives the unit number and filename as well.) Are you sure that the input file is what you think it is? Also, have you given the WHOLE of the error message? Maybe this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220038/list-directed-io-syntax-error-reading-csv-starting-in-first-line-in-fortran

Comment: `u` is an integer. I can not reproduce this error now. The original error was encounter when I run a mpi program on a cluster and that error is resolved by replacing all the integers by floats, which makes me think that's the problem.

Comment: I finally reproduce the error. It is due to a semi-colon accidentally appearing in the data file, it is not related to integer->real conversion. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

the unit 'u' is defined as REAL in fortran by default. The open command expects unit 'u' to be an integer

Define u as an integer and it should work correctly.  Here is the working code.  There is no problem with data conversion of the contents of the file.

```
      real :: a(3)
      integer u
      open(newunit = u,file='t.txt', status='old')
      do j=1,3
         read(u,*) a(j)
      end do
      close(u)

      write (*,*) (i,a(i),i=1,3)
      END
```

Comment: I somehow doubt this is the actual problem but it is hard to say because we do not have the complete code from the OP. But it could be. Did you confirm that it produces the same error message?

Comment: compiled with gfortran, gives an Error: NEWUNIT tag at (1) must be of type INTEGER.  Declaring 'u' as integer fixes the compilation and runs the program correctly.

Comment: That is a different kind of error message.